# How do I deal with this insanity of Flutter's closing requirements?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm constantly getting stuck with the ]'s, }'s and )'s at the end of my widgets:

```
Expanded(
child: TextFormField(
controller: feedbackController,
cursorColor: Colors.white,
style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.white,
),
decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'text input'),
)

]),
)
)

]),
```

I don't know how to deal with this. I find myself wasting so much time just guessing at how to close my triple nested widgets nested within double widgets nested within whatever. It's too convoluted. Is there a finishing tool for building UI's in flutter? An addon that'll close these out for me?

edit: here's what finally closed it.

```
    )

    )]))]
    )
    )]);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://flutterstudio.app/ maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the document to see the widget tree correctly, but basically in your code that you showed above it should be like this:

```
    Expanded(
        child: TextFormField(
      cursorColor: Colors.white,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'text input'),
    )),
```

`Expanded` is a class. In the above code you are initializing the class `Expanded`, and the constructor takes a required `child` argument of type `Widget`. Thus you use the class `TextFormField`.

So basically whenever you use a class you need to use `()`, each class will have many properties which you seperate them using `,` (example `style` is a property which has a value of type `TextStyle` so you initialize the class and close it `),`

You use `[]` when you have a list example the `column` widget has a `children` property which is of type `List<Widget>`. Finally, you use `;` before using `}`. The semicolon indicates an end of statement, example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Text("test")
    );
  }
```

Comment: I just did a code reformat and I see what you're saying. It's a little easier. Thank you